# Measure or detect high current pulse 600A+/15V without osciloscope

Tags: current, pulse

How to measure or detect high current(600-800A) pulse (50-100ms)
**without osciloscope?**

I don't have any osciloscope now, but i need troubleshoot
one spotwelding machine. 
I need to know how much current is going to electrodes.
I don't need exact value of current only to know,
if is current over 500-600A or bellow.

It will be enought turn on LED with some latch circuit 
when is current pulse over some threshold (for example 500A).
or hold/freeze voltage on shunt resistor and read value with slow multimeter.

I don't have multimeter with peek function and cheap multimeter is slow for this.

Any idea how to make workaroud "poorman solution" ?

As shunt resistor i want to use a copper wire with defined length
and know resistivity.(cable from powerbank to electrodes)

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: Do you have access to a PC microphone input? 50-100ms is just in the sound range. (10-20Hz)

Comment: Yes I have, but i am looking for PC-less solution (i know sound osciloscope).  Prefere to learn circuit only solution.

Comment: you could build a peak detector or a $25 oscilloscope.

Answer (score 0):

If the cable is 50mm2, that's 0.35 mOhm/m.

If you use, say a 10cm length of cable as a shunt that's 35µOhm, with 500A current you get 17mV voltage drop. You'll need a low offset opamp to amplify this, say with a gain of 286 so it displays 1V/100A. You can also use a Hall current transducer or a clamp-on ammeter with a signal output.

Then a [peak detector](https://electronicscoach.com/peak-detector.html) and a multimeter.

If you care more about price than accuracy, even an old LM358 should do the job, although its 2mV max input offset will also be amplified and displayed by the multimeter... you'll have to remember to substract it from the measurement.

This should be easy to build with parts from the "junk pile" and a 9V battery.

You can check it works by using a voltage divider on a battery to make a known voltage, say 10mV for example.

Comment: Your answer looks good. Price is not the most important key.

Comment: If you don't mind price, you can use a clamp-on ammeter with fast peak hold or with a signal output, then peak detector

Comment: Sorry my post was not complette (i was disturbed  and you was fast :) ) the rest of my not published post was: availability in local eletronic store (i am not live in city - and I dont have paypall/credit card as the student) I have to use desoldered parts or get what is in local shop (40km away) package from china travell here 6weeks and I want find problem during x-mass vacations. I saw UNI-T clamp ammeter only with HALL sensor and that was slow crap I returned it few years ago. I forgot a model.

Comment: Okay! In this case a circuit with opamps looks the easiest, parts are easy to find...  I'd use the welder cable as a shunt, nail two needles into it through the insulation as measurement probes, you will have to calculate its resistance from the wire gauge. Not very accurate but it should work.

Comment: I checked "local" electronic shop opamps. Which are on stock and I made a list:  LM158(avr?? max 2mV),LM258A(2mV), LM301A(0.7mV),LM318(4mV) ,LM348(1mV),LM358N(3mV), LM2902, LM741(1mV)Thomson, LM2904(2mV), MC1458P(1mV), NE5534(0.5mV out-of-stock), . Most of it has 2-3mV input offset.  Which one ;)? they have same prices less than €0.5. Yeap cables are similiar to welding cables. I am considering milivolt analog meter with custom gauge than multimeter what do you think?

Comment: If you use a peak detector, analog meter will be fine too. If you want to use a single supply opamp, which is more convenient, make sure it specifies "input common mode includes ground" (or includes negative supply) and that output can go all the way to ground. This is true for LM158 258 358 2904 which are all the same opamp, but not true for most of the others.